# nmap reports host up when it isn't

Tags: networking, nmap

On an Ubuntu VMWare VM I ran:

```
sudo nmap -sP 192.168.0.*
```

This returned:

```
Starting Nmap 5.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2010-12-28 22:46 PST

Host 192.168.0.0 is up (0.00064s latency).
Host 192.168.0.1 is up (0.00078s latency).
Host 192.168.0.2 is up (0.00011s latency).
.
.
.
Host 192.168.0.254 is up (0.00068s latency).
Host 192.168.0.255 is up (0.00066s latency).
```

So, nmap reported that every ip in the subnet 192.168.0.* was live. The problem is I only have 4 live machines on 192.168.0.* so why did nmap report every ip address was live?

The ip address of the Ubuntu VM is 192.168.28.131
From this VM I can ping the live systems on  my internal subnet 192.168.0.* and get the expected response. And if I ping a machine that doesn't exist I can get no response as expected.

Answer (score 8):

try the --unprivileged parameter

..like `nmap -sP --unprivileged 192.168.0.*`

Comment: I don't know exactly why, but this did the trick. Without this many IPs are reported as UP even when I have nothing at that address and ping reports no response.

Answer (score 2):

Some firewalls can explain this behavior.

Instead of blocking icmp, they will respond to each echo request they receive.

In this case, it could be due to VMware and the type of virtual network you're using.

Comment: The thing is, if I use the ping command from the VM it works as expected. Why would it behave one way for ping and another for nmap?

Comment: nmap sends not only icmp echo request, but tcp probes also : http://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html
this could explain the difference.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

Switch your network adapter mode to *bridged*.

or

disable *TCP ACK* scan and *ICMP* scan with `--unprivileged` flag.

**Long answer**

Note that `-sP` flag was changed to `-sn` flag.

`-sn` flag checks if target host is up the via following methods

- nmap receives *ICMP* reply to *ICMP ECHO_REQUEST* request
- nmap receives *ICMP* reply to *ICMP TIMESTAMP_REQUEST* request
- nmap receives *TCP* *SYN/ACK* reply to *TCP*(port 443) *SYN* request
- nmap receives *TCP* RST reply to *TCP*(port 80) *ACK* request

If you run nmap scan from VMware machine with network adapter in NAT mode three things may corrupt the scan results:

1. *ICMP TIMESTAMP_REQUEST* reply packets got filtered -> you may miss live hosts.
2. Network generates *TCP RST* reply packets to all *TCP ACK* requests -> all hosts seem to be up.
3. Network responds to all ICMP requests -> all hosts seem to be up.

**References**

nmap man page `-PA` flag

> So remote hosts should always respond with a RST packet, disclosing
> their existence in the process.

nmap man page `-sA` flag

Answer (score -3):

Super quick scan, eliminate the need to return the FQDN (-n)

-sP -PS -n 10.0.0.0/8

Check this out to learn more - https://nmap.org/docs/discovery.pdf

Comment: Is this actually an answer to the question?  I can't tell, suggesting that, at best, it's not a *good* answer.  You may wish to do something about that.