# Nmap takes forever when pinging ports

Tags: nmap

When I execute `nmap -sn  192.168.1.0/24`, it takes 12 seconds to find 256 hosts but when I execute `nmap -sS 192.168.1.0/24`, it takes forever. Why is this happening?

I cannot see what I did wrong. Maybe I wrote my address wrong or something. I am using Kali Linux and the nmap that came installed. It is a virtual machine on a laptop and the connection is wireless.

I was thinking that it could be because of the connection. Should I try making a hotspot with my phone and connecting some stuff to it and then trying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-sn` option pings each target host, but does not do any additional port scanning. Twelve seconds for 256 hosts seems about right.

The `-sS` option sends a Syn packet to each of 65,535 ports on each target host, and then checks for a response. Even though it can do this pretty quickly, it's still doing thousands to tens of thousands of times more activity than the ping-only scan that `-sn` does.

From [Nmap's options summary](https://nmap.org/book/man-briefoptions.html):

> ...
>
> -sn: Ping Scan - disable port scan
>
> ...
>
> -sS/sT/sA/sW/sM: TCP SYN/Connect()/ACK/Window/Maimon scans
>
> …

Comment: i found someting.https://serverfault.com/questions/216938/nmap-reports-host-up-when-it-isnt here you can see tat he has the same problem that all the hosts come up. A guy in the comment said it is a firewall problem and i think he is right becuase i use a VM but he doesnt give any answer